# Type a return value based on input type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have been attempting to use Tuples and Overloading to set the Type of a return value based on the function inputs. There are many posts that seem to suggest this is possible but I just can't seem to get it right. I will paste the tuple method here as this is the easiest to understand what I am trying to achieve. The solution is mostly complicated as the source code spans 3 repositories.

The Tuple method:

The first code block represents a central library which has no specific knowledge of payloads and types:

```
type Dispatcher<T> = (p: T) => boolean | undefined;

export function useEventUtil<T extends [string, any]>(name: T[0]): Dispatcher<T[1]>  {

    return (payload) => {
        return true
    }
}
```

The next block represents a pkg of valid types

```
enum MockEventTypes {
    MockEventType1 = 'MockEventType1',
    MockEventType2 = 'MockEventType2',
}

interface MockEventPayload1 {
    name: string;
}

interface MockEventPayload2 {
    name: number;
}

type AllowedPairs = 
    [MockEventTypes.MockEventType1, MockEventPayload1] | 
    [MockEventTypes.MockEventType2, MockEventPayload2];
```

The final block represents a developer using these utils. As there is no central knowledge of event-types and payload - it is expected that the developer will pass in the AllowedPairs as a Generic. The name argument then should be used to select the correct return type...

```
import { useEventUtil } from 'central-utils'
import { AllowedPairs, MockEventTypes } from 'types-pkg'

const eventUtil = useEventUtil<AllowedPairs>(MockEventTypes.MockEventType1)

eventUtil({
   name: 12
})

// Expected: TS Error as name should not be a number in MockEventPayload1
// Actual: No Error as payload matches MockEventPayload1 | MockEventPayload2
```

I feels like this should be possible (maybe not using tuples)... Can anyone help please?

Comment: Calling `useEventUtil<AllowedPairs>()` gives a `Dispatcher<MockEventPayload1 | MockEventPayload2>` no matter what, so the code is behaving exactly as you're using it.  It sounds like you want `useEventUtil<AllowedPairs>` to *still* be generic and infer an even narrower type `U` compared to `T` from the input `MockeventTypes.MockEventType1`.  But TS doesn't let you specify `T` and have the compiler infer `U`, so you'd have to refactor to something like [this currying approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBdQkW). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yup. @jcalz I think that's the neatest solution.
Thank you. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since `useEventUtil` has only one [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`, and you are explicitly specifying the type argument `AllowedPairs` when calling it, then once you do that the resulting call signature is just

```
  const u = useEventUtil<AllowedPairs>;
  //    ^? const u: (name: MockEventTypes) =>
  //         Dispatcher<MockEventPayload1 | MockEventPayload2>
```

That always returns a `Dispatcher<MockEventPayload1 | MockEventPayload2>` no matter what `name` is.  It looks like you want `useEventUtil<AllowedPairs>` to *still* be generic, so that the specific type of `name` can be used to determine the return type.  Conceptually that would involve adding a second type parameter:

```
// don't try this
declare function useEventUtil<T extends [string, any], U extends T[0]>(
  name: U
): Dispatcher<Extract<T, [U, any]>[1]>;
```

where the `U` is the type of `name`, and the return type involves [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)ing the relevant member of the `T` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

You'd want to be able to manually specify `T` and have the compiler *infer* `U`.  But that doesn't work. TypeScript doesn't currently support so-called *partial type argument inference*. You either specify both `T` and `U` or you let the compiler infer both `T` and `U`.  Neither of which meets your needs.  There's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) to support that, but for now you need to work around it.

---

The most common workaround I use is to [*curry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the function so that instead of `<T, U>(⋯) => ⋯` you get `<T>() => <U>(⋯) => ⋯`.  A generic function where you specify `T`, and you get back another generic function where `U` can be inferred.  For your code that might look like:

```
// this function is apparently so flexible that it can do anything
function useEventUtil(name: string): Dispatcher<any> {
  return (payload) => {
    return true
  }
}

function makeUseEventUtil<T extends [string, any]>():
  <U extends T[0]>(name: U) => Dispatcher<Extract<T, [U, any]>[1]> {
  return useEventUtil
}
```

So `makeUseEventUtil()` just evaluates to `useEventUtil` at runtime. But at compile time you can specify `T` and get back your restricted version of `useEventUtil`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const useEventUtilAllowedPairs = makeUseEventUtil<AllowedPairs>();
/*    ^? const useEventUtilAllowedPairs: <U extends MockEventTypes>(name: U) => 
     Dispatcher<(
       Extract<[MockEventTypes.MockEventType1, MockEventPayload1], [U, any]> | 
       Extract<[MockEventTypes.MockEventType2, MockEventPayload2], [U, any]>
)[1]> */

const eventUtil = useEventUtilAllowedPairs(MockEventTypes.MockEventType1);
//    ^? const eventUtil: Dispatcher<MockEventPayload1>

eventUtil({
  name: 12 // error!
})
```

Looks good. That `useEventUtilAllowedPairs` type might be scary, but it's basically just a new generic function where `U` is constrained to `MockEventTypes` and where the output only gives you the relevant output.  You can see that `eventUtil` is now a `Dispatcher<MockEventPayload1>` as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgZzAQ2AYwBYQE4B4AqAfFALxQAUYAXFPgJSnEBGA9iwDYTIB2UAPlACu3ACYQAZnG4QRAbgBQ87sgC2EJMjTQA8tjgBzKAG95UKOOFpgcFr0EIIAUQBuEbsACq19gSgQAHsBuIghQANoIwHrc+gA0UDwgALqE5MpqNPhhAAxJdDTwGuhYeFkAjCnGimZm2BDAgti8lMgg7CzIIgwkxCY1NXUNTVBRghCmNQC+E9NmaLaRQqRCDi5unt64AILs7QDuMgAKyHDYCIQKZgD0V-0AegD88tNKquooWrAs6gByLMAAdRY2AA1lUzGI0OxkHVzJZrLYVk5XO4vHAfPg-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)